# Not able to access hyperledger cello operator dashboard on 8080 port

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-cello

I installed Cello. I am able to access 8081(user dashboard) but not 8080(operator dashboard). 8080 is already free to use and I can see **"docker-proxy"** using it. I tried changing ports on in docker-composer.yaml but again in logs I can see 8080 is assigned to operator dashboard. So where shall I change the ports so that I can access it on any other port.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your cello path
- open docker-compose.yml

  Change port in operator-dashboard: service

  ```
  ports:
    - "8082:8080"
  ```
- Kill container named *hyperledger/cello-operator-dashboard*

  ```
  docker kill cello-operator-dashboard
  ```
- Remove container named *hyperledger/cello-operator-dashboard*

  ```
  docker rm cello-operator-dashboard
  ```
- Then do

  ```
  make start
  ```
- Now operator dashboard available on http://localhost:8082/

For more information on cello installation refer: [Hyperledger Cello Installation](https://medium.com/@pvrforpranavvr/hyperledger-cello-setup-f31954a9551f)

Comment: operator-dashboard: service has "expose" property not ports

Comment: Use the latest cello repo. Its seems ports here please check
https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

Documentation problem now seem don't have 8080 port dashbroad.
https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/issues/87

> Seems like documentation was out of date. Currently a single login
>   page at port 8081 is used both for admin and users.